# mysql max and group by in 2 table get wrong values

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I've to get the max value "value" in the Logs table for user in the table Users my query seems to works but it pickup the max value but wrong datatime column data

table Users

```
(primary+
unique)
name     | current_list   | other_columns
-----------------------------------------
george       1                data
carl         2                data
paul         1                data
```

table Logs

```
user    |  list  |  value  |  datatime
-------------------------------------
george     1         4       2018-01-01
paul       1         7       2018-01-02  
carl       2         3       2018-01-03  
george     1         5       2018-01-04
paul       2         5       2018-01-05
carl       2         6       2018-01-06
carl       3         8       2018-01-07
george     2         9       2018-01-08
paul       1         8       2018-01-09
george     1         3       2018-01-10
```

Results should be (top value on list chosen "current_list")

```
user    |  other_columns  | top | datatime     
---------------------------------------------
george          data         5    2018-01-04
paul            data         8    2018-01-09
carl            data         6    2018-01-06
```

when i try to show datatime column too i get the wrong data

```
SELECT Logs.datatime,
       Users.*,
       MAX(Logs.value) 
FROM Users, Logs 
WHERE Users.current_list = Logs.list 
  and Users.name = Logs.user 
group by Logs.user
```

is possible solve the problem without subquery?
or i need to use it?
how?

consider that i have an huge database so, fast query is better

Comment: "mysql max and group by in 2 table get wrong values" Yes because you are using GROUP BY wrong.. read https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: You're misusing MySQL's notorious nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: "consider that i have an huge database so, fast query is better" Share the `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` for all tables involved so we can see the indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find the biggest value for each one.

```
SELECT U.name, U.current_list, MAX(L.value) as m_value
FROM Users U          
JOIN Logs U
  ON U.name = L.user    
 AND U.current_list = L.list
GROUP BY U.name, U.current_list
```

Then get the rest of the fields

```
SELECT U.*, L.Value
FROM Users U
JOIN Logs U
  ON U.name = L.user    
 AND U.current_list = L.list
JOIN ( SELECT U.name, U.current_list, MAX(L.value) as m_value
       FROM Users U          
       JOIN Logs U
         ON U.name = L.user    
        AND U.current_list = L.list
       GROUP BY U.name, U.current_list
     ) T
  ON U.name = T.name
 AND U.current_list = L.current_list
 AND L.value= T.m_value
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland fixed

Comment: I dont need max datatime, I need max Log.value for each user in the selected list with the right datatime field

Comment: well easy, change datatime for value :)

Comment: great works! just add it L.datatime after first select becouse i need it :)